# Using UITableView without a storyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8, tableview

I'm trying to set a tableView as a subview in my viewController. But without using the storyboard! I'm trying this code, but it doesn't seem to work and I can't understand why..
So this is the code in which the tableview should be created:

```
func TableView(position: CGRect, allRecipes: [Recipe]) -> UITableView {
    let tableView: UITableView = UITableViewForAllRecipes(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain).tableView


    return tableView;
}
```

.

and this is my tableviewcontroller (UITableViewForAllRecipes)

```
class UITableViewForAllRecipes: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel.text = "ok"

    return cell
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    println("nosit")
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    println("tv")
    return 3
}
```

}

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? As it doesn't even seem to print those "nosit" and "tv", so It doesn't reach that code.. I didn't get anything out of debugging also..

Comment: After the `TableView` function return, the `UITableViewForAllRecipes` view controller will be deallocated.

Comment: @Swipesight When I move the code so that the tableview is directly added as a subview of my viewController, it still is empty and doesn't reach the println-code in my controller

Comment: Basically you should not create the table view like that, the table view return from `TableView` function will have its data source and delegate point to the view controller which is deallocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Swipesight is right. The reason why you see an empty tableview:

- You create an instance of UITableViewForAllRecipes, the tableview controller holds a tableview and itself as that tableview's datasource and delegate.
- Then you grab the tableview, add it as a subview, but since tableview holds its delegate as weak reference, when you quit the TableView() func, the tableviewcontroller itself is released, since no more strong ref.
- When the tableview being rendered, it asks its datasource, which is nil and you get an empty table view.

Possible fix:

> Hold a strong ref to your tableviewcontroller in your parent view controller

e.g

```
func TableViewController(position: CGRect, allRecipes: [Recipe]) -> UITableViewForAllRecipes {
    return UITableViewForAllRecipes(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
}
```

add a property in your parent view controller

```
var tableViewController: UITableViewForAllRecipes?
```

Then in your function where you call TableView

```
self.tableViewController = self.TableViewController(xxxx)
self.view.addSubview(self.tableViewController!.tableView)
```

Comment: allright, I now understand why it is empty when shown, but I dont' understand why it still doesn't reach the code while debugging and how I can hold that strong ref.
Maybe I'm looking at this all wrong of course, is there any other way to get a filled tableview in my mainview?

Comment: @Shuo When you add the child’s view, you need to ensure that events continue to be distributed to both view controllers. You do this by explicitly associating the new view controller as a child of the container. - Excerpt From “View Controller Programming Guide for iOS” by Apple

Comment: @JayEss Are you building a container view controller which has a table view controller as child or just want to build a table view controller programmatically?

Comment: @Swipesight The first one. What i was trying to do was pretty much have a view that contained a tableview as a subview. So not using the tableview as a mainview. And of course show a filled table, not a blank one

Answer (score 1):

How you implement your view controller which has a table view added to its view hierarchy  depends on whether you need a separate view controller to manage the table view.

If you do require a separate view controller, then

```
class UITableViewForAllRecipes: UITableViewController {

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                var cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

                cell.textLabel.text = "ok"

                return cell
        }

        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                println("nosit")
                return 1
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                println("tv")
                return 3
        }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
        let childTableViewController = UITableViewForAllRecipes(style: .Plain)
        let otherView = UIView()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                // TODO: setup otherView's frame, autoresizingMask ...

                view.addSubview(otherView)

                addChildViewController(childTableViewController)

                let tableView = childTableViewController.tableView

                // TODO: setup tableView's frame, autoresizingMask ...

                view.addSubview(tableView)

                childTableViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        }
}
```

otherwise

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        let otherView = UIView()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                // TODO: setup otherView's frame, autoresizingMask ...

                view.addSubview(otherView)

                // TODO: setup tableView's frame, autoresizingMask ...

                tableView.dataSource = self
                tableView.delegate = self

                view.addSubview(tableView)
        }

        // MARK: - UITableViewControllerDataSource

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                var cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

                cell.textLabel.text = "ok"

                return cell
        }

        func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                println("nosit")
                return 1
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                println("tv")
                return 3
        }
}
```